# How can I adjust the width of an Iframe with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, zuora

```
<div style="width: 550px;" id="zuora_payment">
    <div style="display: inline;" class="z-overlay" id="z-overlay"></div>
    <div class="z-container" id="z-container">
        <div class="z-data" id="z-data">
            <iframe style="display: block;" class="z_hppm_iframe" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" overflow="visible" id="z_hppm_iframe" src="https://www.zuora.com/allowtransparencypps/PublicHostedPageLite.do?..." frameborder="0" height="912" width="300">
            </iframe>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried: `document.getElementById('z_hppm_iframe').setAttribute("style","width:500px");`

I just need to adjust the width of the iFrame element, but it shows as null in the console, so I guess I'm not selecting the element correctly.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

The iFrame is added dynamically inside a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {}
```

which is is in head of the page. So I suspect it is not available at the time the .setAttribute() runs which is inside a script tag at the end of the body. I'm not doing much in this area (as you can tell), so I just need to figure out how to run this line of js after the iframe is added (I guess).

Comment: Have you tried `setAttribute('width', '500px')`?

Comment: Are you sure the element is available when you are attempting to modify it? Try wrapping your code in `window.load = function(){}`

Comment: Did you open the browsers console?

Comment: @KirkB You are using getElementBy**Id** on a class, that's why the iframe is null. See my answer.

Comment: @KirkB disrgard last post I see that you do have an id for iframe.

Comment: Yea, I found it confusing that the class and id had the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use the element before it was even rendered by the browser.

You should place your `<script>` tag just before ending the `body` tag.

Another solution is to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event, e.g:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('z_hppm_iframe').setAttribute("style", "width:500px");
});
```

---

I suggest you to change the width by doing `style.width = '500px';`, instead of doing by attribute, because doing the way you are, the `style` attribute will going to be completely replaced.

Comment: So inside the function should look like: document.getElementById('z_hppm_iframe').style.width = '500px';

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that you're trying to use the element before it was even rendered by the browser.

^ Well that only pertains to the method the OP tried. However, since the Iframe is being added dynamically and because the DOM does not need to be rendered in order to manipulate objects, he really doesn't need to move his **<script>** tags to the bottom of the page. Therefore, we cannot say that this is the source of the problem.

**as to the OP**...

> The iFrame is added dynamically...

since "width" is technically one attribute and "style", another...

```
var iframe = document.create('iframe');
iframe.width = 500;
//or
iframe.style.width = '500px';
```

hopefully this helps